# Google Play Services doesn't work on Huawei devices when in IDLE mode

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, huawei-developers

We tried wake_lock, we tried to switch from Transition API to Activity Recognition API, we tried to get update via IntentService and BroadcastReceiver, but the problem remains when the phone goes offline(no wifi and no Mobile data) and the screen turns off. In this case our application stops receiving information from the API(onHandleIntent if we work with IntentService or onReceive if we work with BroadcastReceiver is never started).

We also test with Huawei Y6S EMUI 9.1 phone but the problem is the same again.

We noticed that when the phone goes offline and the screen turns off  in logcat, this stops appearing:

12-03 13:57:16.965  1366  2098 W AlarmManager: mIsScreenOn is: true, WAKEUP alarm trigger action = com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_ACTIVITY_DETECTION package name is: com.google.android.gms
12-03 13:57:16.988  1366  5998 V BroadcastQueue: Finished with ordered broadcast BroadcastRecord{855fb8a u0 com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_ACTIVITY_DETECTION}

Is it possible that GooglePlayServices is stoped in this case?

Comment: I think it is not related to GMS. It is an EMUI process control issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google doc for ActivityRecognitionAPI -

To conserve battery, activity reporting may stop when the device is **'STILL'** for an extended
period of time. It will resume once the device moves again. This only happens on devices that support the Sensor.**TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION** hardware.
Beginning in API 21, activities may be received less frequently than the detectionIntervalMillis parameter if the device is in power save mode and the screen is off.

Please check your device. What other HUAWEI devices have been used for testing?
Also, this interface is deprecated, use ActivityRecognitionClient.